# Getting only x or y position from sprite in compass?

Tags: compass-sass

If I use

```
@import "icon/*.png";
@include all-icon-sprites;
```

I can use

```
background-position: sprite-position($icon, foobar);
```

to get the xy position of the foobar-icon.
Is it possible to get only the x or y value within the sprite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
$x: nth(sprite-position($icon, foobar), 1);
$y: nth(sprite-position($icon, foobar), 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason something like `sprite-position-y` isn't available is because `background-position-y` isn't in the official CSS spec. The recommendation to add it [has been denied](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Tracker/issues/9). Chrome, Safari, and even IE support it but Opera and Firefox do not ([support table](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/background-position-x-y)).

It may be possible to write your own extension to calculate and return the value, but you are better off updating both x and y.